# Django conditional expressions in queries

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I have two models, one with `ForeignKey` I'm trying to match. In order to do so, I'm looking up second model by a specific number and a date. The problem is it has two dates and I have to make decision on which date to choose. Under some circumstances it is set to NULL, in some it is not. If it is I have to get the second date field. I have something like this:

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    model2_key = models.ForeignKey(MyModel2)
    model1_date=...
    model1_number=...
```

second model:

```
class MyModel2(models.Model):
    model2_date1=...
    model2_date2=...
    model2_number=...
```

Now, how to make the choice? I have looked up documentation regarding `F expressions`, `Q expressions`, `When expressions`, `Select` and I'm a little bit confused. How can I wrtie a function that returns searched `MyModel2` object? I have something like this, but it won't work.

```
def _find_model2(searched_date, searched_number):
    searched_model2=MyModel2.objects.get(Q(model2_number=searched_number),
                    Q(When(model2_date1__e='NULL', then=model2_date2) |
                    Q(When(model2_date1__ne='NULL', then=model2_date1))=searched_date))
```

I am quite new to django, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a workaround this issue, I don't think it's mostefficient and elegant one, but it works. Should anyone have a better solution please post it.

First, all objects whose corresponding dates match are called:

```
from_query = list(MyModel2.objects.filter(Q(model2_date1__range=
(datetime_min, datetime_max)) | Q(model2_date2__range=(datetime_min, datetime_max)),
  model2_number=searched_number))
```

Then I iterate over found objects:

```
to_return = []
for item in from_query:
    if item.model2_date1:
        to_return.append(item)
    elif datetime_min <= item.model2_date2 <= datetime_max:
        to_return.append(item)
```

EDIT: I've come up with a solution. Assuring that `model2_date1__isnull=True` is enough. The solution now looks like this:

```
from_query = list(MyModel2.objects.get((Q(model2_date1__range=(datetime_min, datetime_max)) |
                                              Q(Q(model2_date2__range=(datetime_min, datetime_max)),
                                                Q(model2_date1__isnull=True)),
                                              model2_number=searched_number))
```

Comment: Does `MyModel2.objects.filter(Q(model2_date1=searched_date) | Q(model2_date2=searched_date)).filter(model2_number=searched_number)` not work?

Comment: One of the dates is sometimes set up sometimes not and this is the criterion upon which I have to decide whether the object matches query or not.